# Why won't my icon center to my other two sections?

Tags: html, css, icons

I'm having trouble centering my edit button two my like section and comment sections, respectively. The edit icon seems to be off centered and I'm not sure how to exactly center it without forcing an offset onto it. Here is the screenshot below of what the issue is:

[image: Edit Button not centered]

Here is the relevant html and css:

**html**

```
<div class="tweet-actions-section">

    <div class="edit-section">
        <!-- Edit Button -->
        <button class="edit-button">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">edit_square</span>
            <span class="tooltiptext">Edit Post</span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="like-section">
        <!-- Like Button -->
        <button class="like-button">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">favorite</span>
            <span class="tooltiptext">Like</span>
        </button>
        <!-- Like Counter -->
        <span class="like-counter">0 Likes</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="comment-section">
        <!-- Comment Button -->
        <button class="comment-button">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">chat_bubble</span>
            <span class="tooltiptext">Comment</span>
        </button>
        <!-- Comment Counter -->
        <span class="like-counter">0 Comments</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tweet-actions-section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 60%;
}

.like-section, .comment-section, .edit-section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 0.6rem;
    transition: 0.1s color ease;
}

.edit-button, .like-button, .comment-button {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: none;
    background: none; 
    padding: 0; 
}

.edit-button .material-symbols-outlined {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

I have tried putting the button within another div and making it a flexbox but that doesn't work either. I just want the icon to be centered along with the other two sections. If you have any tips, please let me know!

Comment: I am going to assume you are using the Material Symbols from Google. It seems to be that the icons themselves are all drawn in a square canvas. The `edit_square` icon has been drawn to use more of its canvas than the `favorite` or `chat_bubble` icons. Also consider that the `edit_square` icon is more "bottom heavy", whereas the `favorite` and `chat_bubble` icons are "top heavy" which exacerbates to misalignment. You would need to reimplement the icons and edit their SVG source code, or use "manual" offsets.

Comment: @Wongjn Yea I essentially just used a slight manual offset to solve the issue